# PayPal - Hybris integration, what is best practice to modify order and re-auth the transaction?

Tags: paypal, sap-commerce-cloud

We are in process of integrating PayPal - Hybris using the Hybris plug-in. PayPal has a 3 day honor period before they allow order to be modified. Does anyone has deal with this scenario?

Comment: "3 days before they allow the order to be modified" ? I think you are misunderstanding something you read. That's not a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Per PayPall documentation " Within the 29-day authorization period, you can issue multiple re-authorizations after the honor period expires. And their default honor period is 3 days which i feel to long. so wondering is there any way to hanle this. "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/admin/auth-capture/?mark=autho#overview. Which i fee

Answer (score 0):

Re-authorizations *only* exist to obtain a new 3 day honor period (there is no other purpose for re-authorizations, at all), and so in general are completely unnecessary. Don't worry about re-authorizations.

Instead, worry about captures. You can capture at any time during the 29 day window, regardless of whether you re-authorized or not.

Comment: ya, capture is no issue. Our scenario is once the order is placed and the customer reaches out for immediate changes to order how should we handle this scenario as PayPal does not allow to modify the order within honor period?    We can obviously cancel that order and ask customer to create new order but that won't be good User EXP so trying to figure out what is the best way to handle this. Any help would be appriciated.